# Gson unbable to invoke no-args construktor for observer ( LiveData) in my Android & Kotlin project

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, android-room, android-livedata

I already read a lot of stack**overflow** articles and other blog posts about it trying out different solutions for the similar (*but not same*) problems they had there.

I will structure this post as follows:

1. My problem
2. My code (the part I think is relevant)
3. What I tried to fix it

## 1. My Problem

I'm getting the following error message:

```
    Process: com.myapp, PID: 23553
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for androidx.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap$SupportRemove<androidx.lifecycle.Observer<? super java.lang.Integer>, androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$ObserverWrapper>. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
        at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$14.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:228)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:212)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:186)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:932)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:897)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:846)
        at com.myapp.ui.customGame.CustomGameViewModel.initialize(CustomGameViewModel.kt:46)
```

#### Description of what I am trying to achieve:

I'm writing an app as a project for learning programming in Kotlin and making apps in general, I'm relatively new to making apps and Kotlin, bear that in mind if you see me making stupid mistakes, please ;).
In my app, I have an activity that contains a fragment that lets you choose the settings for a game of Volleyball (the CustomGameSetupFragment). The settings include simple things like the final score a team wins at, the names etc. After the settings are chosen and saved, the app creates an object of the Game class with the settings applied, saves them to a Room database. An entity in the table of my database basically contains an ID, some other information, and a JSON string of the game object (created via Google's Gson package). The activity then replaces the fragment with the fragment that lets you count the score of the game and see the names and stuff (the CustomGameFragment). The new fragment creates a ViewModel object which then again reads the games from the database, picks the last saved entities and then tries to recreate the game object from the JSON string saved.
This is done by executing:

```
val gameType = object: TypeToken<Game>() {}.type
this.game = Gson().fromJson<Game>(
    gameRepo.ongoingGameData[0].gameJson,
    gameType
    //Game::class.java // this was an other method I tried. Also didnt work
)
```

Before, the Game class contained no LiveData/MutableLiveData but that resulted in the necessity to cast the attributes into LiveData/MutableLiveData in the ViewModel class and **that** resulted in a lot of bugs. ***But it worked!***. I refactored the Game class so it mostly LiveData/MutableLiveData attributes (the ones I need to be LiveData), since in the CustomGameFragment and its ViewModel that would allow me to simply observe the attributes of the game directly. But **after** I refactored the class, Gson is not able to load it anymore.
I'm not sure it's simply because I use LiveData, and they somehow need the context or viewLifeCylceOwner that they get implicitly in the ViewModel or something.

## 2. My Code

#### a) The Room database (with Repository, Entity, Dao, Database)

Entity:

```
package com.myapp.data

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "gameData_table")
data class GameData(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "gid") val gid: String?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "is_over") val isOver : Boolean?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "team1_name") val team1Name: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "team2_name") val team2Name: String?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "team1_sets") val team1Sets: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "team2_sets") val team2Sets: Int?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "total_sets") val totalSets: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "game_json") val gameJson : String?

    )
```

The Dao:

```
package com.myapp.data

import androidx.room.*

@Dao
interface GameDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM gameData_table")
    suspend fun getAll(): List<GameData>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM gameData_table WHERE id = (:id)")
    fun loadAllByIds(id: Array<Int>): List<GameData>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM gameData_table WHERE is_over = 0")
    suspend fun getOngoing() : List<GameData>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertAll(vararg game: GameData)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(game: GameData)

    @Query("DELETE FROM gameData_table WHERE is_over = 0")
    suspend fun deleteOngoing()

    @Query("UPDATE gameData_table SET game_json = (:json) WHERE gid = (:gameId)")
    suspend fun updateJSON(json: String, gameId : String)
}
```

The Database:

```
package com.myapp.data

import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase

@Database(entities = [GameData::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class GameDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun gameDao() : GameDao

    companion object {
        //Singleton pattern to prevent multiple instances of the database

        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: GameDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context) : GameDatabase {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this){
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    GameDatabase::class.java,
                    "game_database"
                ).build()

                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
```

The Repository:

```
package com.myapp.data

import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

class GameRepository (private val gameDao: GameDao){
    val allGameData: List<GameData> = runBlocking { gameDao.getAll()}
    val ongoingGameData : List<GameData> = runBlocking { gameDao.getOngoing() }

    suspend fun insert(gameData : GameData){
        gameDao.insertAll(gameData)
    }

    suspend fun deleteOngoing() {
        gameDao.deleteOngoing()
    }

    suspend fun updateGame(gameData : GameData){
        gameDao.updateJSON(gameData.gameJson!!, gameData.gid!!)
    }

}
```

#### b) The Game class

And now a very short version of the game, since most of the methods are not really relevant for my problem I think:

```
package com.myapp.game

import android.app.Application
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import com.myapp.data.GameData
import com.myapp.values.Values
import com.google.gson.Gson

class Game {


    /*
    No live data needed or possible?
     */
    private var sets : MutableList<Set>
    private val pointGap : Int = Values.DEFAULT_POINT_GAP
    private val gid : String = this.toString()

    /*
    Live data needed or possible
     */

    // private MutableLiveData
    private var _team1Name : MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData(Values.DEFAULT_TEAM1_NAME)
    (more strings ...)
    private var _setWinScore : MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData(Values.DEFAULT_WIN_SCORE)
    (...)

    // public LiveData
    val team1Name : LiveData<String>
    (more strings ...)
    val setWinScore : LiveData<Int>
    (...)


    init{
        team1Name = _team1Name
        (more strings ...)
        setWinScore = _setWinScore
        (...)

    }


    constructor(gameSettings: GameSettings = GameSettings()){
        this._team1Name.value = gameSettings.team1Name
        (more strings...)
        this._setWinScore.value = gameSettings.setWinScore
        (...)
    }
}
```

## 3. Approaches to fix it#

I tried to use a InstanceCreator. But after I read some stuff about it, I found that this is neccessary if the object you want to recreate has an argument of something the Gson class needs to know to put it in (context for example). I don't have that, I think (?).
I tried it anyway, which of course didn't work.
Also I tried several variations of using TypeToken which I also have shown at the beginning.

Another thing I read often, was to use the newest version of the package Gson, Room and LiveData or to use kapt instad of implement keywords in the grandle.build at project level.
I tried both -> same Exception

## So, do you have any ideas?

Or am I doing something stupidly wrong?
Thanks in advance for sacrificing your time!

PS: I'm not an English native speaker, so sorry for bad grammar and spelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following shows how to deserialize `LiveData`, however maybe in your use case it would be more appropriate to share the `Game` data as `ViewModel`? See [Android Developers page](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing).

---

When no custom or built-in type adapter matches, Gson uses a reflection-based one. The problem is that you are asking Gson to deserialize JSON as `LiveData`. If you look at the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/lifecycle/lifecycle-livedata-core/src/main/java/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData.java) of `LiveData` you will see that is has multiple private fields and for the type of one of them Gson cannot create instances.

In general it is discouraged to use Gson's reflection-based serialization or deserialization for any third party classes (here `LiveData`) because you then rely on their internal implementation details which could change at any point.

This can be solved by creating a custom [`TypeAdapterFactory`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.6/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html).
I am not familiar with Kotlin, but hopefully the following Java code is useful for you as example nonetheless:

```java
class LiveDataTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
  public static final LiveDataTypeAdapterFactory INSTANCE = new LiveDataTypeAdapterFactory();
  
  private LiveDataTypeAdapterFactory() { }
  
  @Override
  public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
    Class<?> rawType = type.getRawType();
    // Only handle LiveData and MutableLiveData
    if (rawType != LiveData.class && rawType != MutableLiveData.class) {
      return null;
    }
    
    // Assumes that LiveData is never used as raw type but is always parameterized
    Type valueType = ((ParameterizedType) type.getType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    // Get the adapter for the LiveData value type `T`
    // Cast TypeAdapter to simplify adapter code below
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    TypeAdapter<Object> valueAdapter = (TypeAdapter<Object>) gson.getAdapter(TypeToken.get(valueType));
    
    // Is safe due to `type` check at start of method
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    TypeAdapter<T> adapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) new TypeAdapter<LiveData<?>>() {
      @Override
      public void write(JsonWriter out, LiveData<?> liveData) throws IOException {
        // Directly write out LiveData value
        valueAdapter.write(out, liveData.getValue());
      }
      
      @Override
      public LiveData<?> read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        Object value = valueAdapter.read(in);
        return new MutableLiveData<>(value);
      }
    };
    return adapter;
  }
}
```

(Note that this does not retain the observers of the `LiveData`)

You can then create the `Gson` instance using a [`GsonBuilder`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.6/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html) and register the factory:

```java
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
  .registerTypeAdapterFactory(LiveDataTypeAdapterFactory.INSTANCE)
  .create();
```

There is no need to use `TypeToken` when deserializing `Game`, using the class directly will work as well. `TypeToken` is intended for generic types.

Ideally you would also create a `TypeAdapterFactory` for `MutableList` to not rely on its internal implementation.